# How to compare six integer variables and show which one it's the bigger one

Tags: java, android, int

In my application, I have six integer variables (int) and I want to compare them and choose the bigger one but I don't know how to do that. Could you help me please?

Comment: no, they are int (integer), maybe I have to put them in an array =)

Comment: What has this to do with eclipse or android? What language are you using?

Comment: Java, I'm doing an Android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 int max = array[0];
 for (int counter = 1; counter < array.length; counter++)
        {
             if (array[counter] > max)
             {
              max = array[counter];
             }
        }

    System.out.println("The maximum number is: " + max);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
      int numbers[] = new int[] {4,6,....};
      int max = numbers[0];
      for(int indx=1; indx<numbers.length; indx++){
         if(max< numbers[indx]){
             max = numbers[indx];
         }
      }
      System.out.println("max=="+max);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have to try this,

```
max=array[0];
 for (int counter = 1; counter < array.length; counter++)
{
     if (array[counter] > max)
     {
      max = array[counter];
     }
}

System.out.println("The maximum number is: " + max);
```

It works 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple bubble sort method and then choose the last element which will give you the biggest integer value.

You can find pseudo code here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

PS: Only use bubble sort because you have only six elements. Otherwise it is discouraging to use bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 scheme for your task:

firstly you should put these data into an array ,and that will make your work easier.

1.iterate all the data and select the biggest one

```
int biggest=-10000000;//this is just a compare tag
for(i=0;i<6;i++)
{
   if(array[i]>biggest)
       biggest=array[i];
}
printf("%d\n",biggest);
```

2.sort this array,for instance ,rank these data ascendingly.

so just choose the max index of this array as max value;